# Can't select Photos library. Click Choose Library, nothing happens

Tags: photos.app

I have 3 iPhoto Libraries. Have already converted 2 of them. Went back to open the first converted and it would not open. Nothing.

I can select the other two, but when I try and select the 3rd, nothing happens. I click, the button registers the click, but nothing happens.

Here is a screenshot - I click Choose Library and nothing happens.

[image: click choose library nothing happens]

I can select the other libraries, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

That Library is showing as a .migratedlibrary file, which means it's already been 'translated' to Photos format & can no longer be opened in Photos.

The contents must be in one of your other libraries in the list, or if on a remote disk, you may have to open it fro the `Other Library…' button.
By default, the new Photos Library will be in the same location as the old iPhoto Library it was imported from.

From [How Photos for Mac handles iPhoto imports](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/02/11/photos-mac-iphoto-import/)

> So, when Photos migrates an iPhoto library, it changes the file extension on the iPhoto library package to .migratedphotolibrary and makes a hard link to all iPhoto media assets in its own library package, using the same directory structure as iPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, renaming the iPhoto Library and then relaunching Photos worked. It loaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that trying to open the .photolibrary bundle manually in Finder worked just fine when only the .migratedphotolibrary bundle showed up in the choose library pane.